# how to configure WCF in BizTalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I want to send data to web service and receive data response from the same web service

Anyone have a tutorial for configuring binding in BizTalk administration?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259973.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use the BizTalk WCF Service Consuming Wizard to generate schema and binding information for the port (that you asked for). This is done from a locally saved wsdl or directly if there is a MEX point exposed.
A guide can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226552.aspx

For detailed information about the WCF adapters in 2010 can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259952.aspx